# Complex STAT GROUP BY for Yii

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, relational

I'm trying to do a complex STAT within the relation function of the model.

Basically:

```
'stats' => array(self::STAT, 'Comments', 'post_id', 'select'=>'COUNT(id) AS total_comments, SUM(comment_rating) AS comment_rating')
```

But Yii won't allow that. So I've done a self::HAS_ONE but Yii does a join and group by on the ENTIRE query upon retrieval of model data.

I want to either get the STAT working so it does one group by for different data, OR get it to the effect where the raw SQL becomes

```
SELECT * FROM Posts p LEFT JOIN (SELECT .....) AS comments_data CD ON p.id=CD.post_id
```

Is any of this possible?

Comment: Do you get an error message when you try that?

Comment: yes I do get an error message

Comment: Well for goodness sake, whatever you do, don't tell us what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two STAT relations:

```
'commentCount'=>array(self::STAT, 'Comment', 'post_id'),
'ratingSum'=>array(self::STAT, 'Comment', 'post_id', 'select'=>'SUM(comment_rating)'),
```

There is no way to combine them into one using STAT.